# Using native SDK in React Native or Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, react-native

I intend to develop an app for our site but one of the main worry is that I need to use a 3rd party payment gateway that only provides SDK for android in Java and iOS in Objective-C.

I want to know if it is appropriate to use React-Native or Ionic for the app. I am not sure which of these framework supports integration of native integrated and work flawlessly.

Hope someone with experience can help advise on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For react-native you can write your native modules for both android(JAVA) and ios(OBJECTIVE-C). It provides you right to write code in module and then register the module for your further use inside your application.

You can read the complete docs from :-

**For android** https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

and **for ios** https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: If somebody has the same requirement in Flutter. Here is complete instruction

https://medium.com/@milindmevada/integrating-third-party-native-sdks-in-flutter-df418829dcf7

Comment: is it not possible for ionic?